# How to get all installed features in rcp 4 application

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, e4

I'm trying to get a list of features that are installed through code. How can I programmatically list all installed features?

Comment: I am trying to get features by below code ::: 
IBundleGroupProvider[] providers = Platform.getBundleGroupProviders();
IBundleGroup[] groups = providers[0].getBundleGroups();

but I got an exception :: 
org.eclipse.debug.core.DebugException: com.sun.jdi.ClassNotLoadedException: Type has not been loaded occurred while retrieving component type of array.

Comment: The bundle group providers list is always empty in a pure e4 application as the code to populate it is not included.

Comment: Do you have any idea how can I get all installed features?

Comment: I spent some time yesterday looking but as far as I can see e4 does not have this information.

Comment: I found that there is a 'platform.xml' that you can read - see updated answer

Answer (score 1):

In a pure e4 application the

```java
IBundleGroupProvider[] providers = Platform.getBundleGroupProviders();
```

call always returns an empty array because the code that populates the list (`org.eclipse.update.configurator`) is not included.

There does not appear to be anything in e4 that has the features list.

The RCP build does create a `platform.xml` file in the `configuration/org.eclipse.update` directory in the RCP installation which contains the features list. You could try reading this.

Note that the `platform.xml` does not exist if you just run your RCP using 'Run as Eclipse Application` from within Eclipse. It only exists in the exported RCP.